# VBA to insert new row from table with formula

Tags: excel, vba, row, addition

I have VBA code to add new rows to a table (data starts in row 5).

I made a new sheet and it works pretty well when the table doesn't have headers. When I add headers, however, the following error pops up

> run-time error '1004' this won't work because it would
>   move cells in a table on your worksheet.

I click debug and it highlights `Rng.Insert Shift:=x1Down`

What is the reason for the error and how can it be corrected?

```
Sub AddRows()

    Const BaseRow As Long = 5   ' modify to suit

    Dim x As String             ' InputBox returns text if 'Type' isn't specified
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    R = BaseRow + CInt(x) - 1

    Rows(BaseRow).Copy          'Copy BaseRow
    'specify range to insert new cells
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(BaseRow, 1), Cells(R, 1))
    Rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    ' insert the new rows BEFORE BaseRow
    ' to insert below BaseRow use Rng.Offset(BaseRow - R)
    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(BaseRow - R - 1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    Rng.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False '
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have headers, your baserow would be +1?

Comment: Do you have any other tables below the one you are inserting rows into?

Comment: no, its one big table

Comment: I tried R = BaseRow + CInt(x) + 1 but no joy. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I think your table is a listobject. Then the following code might work

```
Sub TestAdd()
Dim myTbl As ListObject
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long

    Set myTbl = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")

    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To CInt(x)
        myTbl.ListRows.Add (1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Update**: For keeping the format and formulas you could use the following code

```
Sub TestAdd()

Dim myTbl As ListObject
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long
Dim newRow As Range
Dim sngCell As Range

    Set myTbl = Sheets("Rentals").ListObjects(1)
    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To CInt(x)
        Set newRow = myTbl.ListRows.Add(1).Range
        With newRow
            .Offset(1).Copy
            ' .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            For Each sngCell In newRow
                If Not (sngCell.HasFormula) Then
                    sngCell.ClearContents
                End If
            Next
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please learn to tell where the error pops up? I assume at _Sheet1.ListObjects(1)_. Then either my assumption is wrong or the listobject is not on Sheet1. Do you know which sheet the data is on? And do you know the name, either the codename or the sheet name which you see in the tab on the bottom?

Comment: Thanks. I changed sheet1 to "Rentals" to match my sheet. The error now reads object required.

Comment: How does your code look like now? Either you use the codename or you need to change the line to `Set myTbl = Sheets("Rentals").ListObjects(1)`.

Comment: Sub TestAdd()
Dim myTbl As ListObject
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long

    Set myTbl = Sheets("Rentals").ListObjects(1)
    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")

    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To CInt(x)
        myTbl.ListRows.Add (1)
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: ok, this inserts new rows but there are a few format issues and not all the formulas are copied in. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, It is inserting rows. But it is not inserting the same format and formula from the rows below.

Comment: An error pops up saying subscript out of range. I don't understand the "Tabelle4"

Comment: I could send you the document if that makes it easier to understand?

Comment: I just replaced it with your table name  :-)

Comment: Ok this is exciting. it is very close. Some columns (appears random) I, O and Q copy the header colour cell into the new rows. A couple other columns don't centre the data like the others. Any ideas?

Comment: The code works with my data and table. Anyway, I did a small modification to the code, maybe this fixes your issue.

Comment: YAAAAASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I needed to use Offset(-1) to copy from the row above the one I was adding